# Equation of a line tangent to a circle: why it works?

Tags: calculus

I've the problem following: "Determine the points on the circumference of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ whose tangent lines are 
and the point $(3,0)$." I found the derivative $\dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=-\dfrac{x}{y}$ and I managed to solve the exercise by doing something like:

$y^2 = 1 - x^2\\
y - f(p) = f'(p)\cdot(x-p) \quad (1)\\
y - 0 = -\dfrac{x}{y}\cdot(x - 3)\\
y^2 = -x^2 + 3x\\
x = \dfrac{1}{3}\\$

From there I managed to get the correct equation of the line tangent to the circle as required by the exercise. But when I do $x=3$ in the line (1), I get:

$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{1-3^2}}\cdot(x-3)$,

which results in some strange stuff. Then I don't know if the way I solved it is the correct one. If it is, why I can't obtain $x=\dfrac{1}{3}$ when $x=3$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just need to be a bit more careful: $x^2+y^2=1$ is the equation for the circle and $y - f(p) = f^\prime(p)\cdot(x-p)$ is the equation of the line. They will only intersect at the tangent point, which is clearly not going to be when $x = 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do it the calculus way (there is a much simpler geometric way).

Let the point(s) of tangency be $(a,b)$. Then by your calculation, the slope of the tangent line is $-\frac{a}{b}$.

The tangent line, we are told, goes through the *external* point $(3,0)$. The line joining $(a,b)$ to $(3,0)$ has slope $\frac{b}{a-3}$. Thus we arrive at
the equation
$$\frac{b}{a-3}=-\frac{a}{b}.$$
Simplification gives $b^2=-a(a-3)$ and therefore $a^2+b^2=3a$. But $a^2+b^2=1$, and therefore $3a=1$. It follows that $a=\frac{1}{3}$. A picture, or algebra, shows there are two tangent lines, since $a^2+b^2=1$ yields two values of $b$.

Much closer to what you did is to find the *equation* of the tangent line. The tangent line has slope $-\frac{a}{b}$ and passes through $(a,b)$. It follows that an equation of the tangent line(s) is
$$y-b=-\frac{a}{b}(x-a).$$
Substitute the point $(3,0)$ for $(x,y)$. Some algebra, together with $a^2+b^2=1$, gives us the desired result.

**Remark:** It is **very** important not to let $(x,y)$ be the mystery point(s) of tangency, for that risks confusion with the *variables* used in describing the equation of the tangent line.

For an approach using analytic geometry, let the point(s) of tangency be $P=(a,b)$. Note that the line through $P$ and $(3,0)$ is perpendicular to the line $OP$. It follows by the Pythagorean Theorem that
$$(a-3)^2+b^2+1^2=3^2.$$
Some algebra, together with $a^2+b^2=1$, yields $a=\frac{2}{6}$.

Or else we can use the fact that the line $OP$ has slope $\frac{b}{a}$ and therefore the tangent line at $P$ has slope $-\frac{a}{b}$. Now use the calculation of the first solution.

Comment: Very enlightening and beautiful, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. The unfortunate thing about calling the point of tangency $(x,y)$ is that an incorrect argument fairly often leads to the right numerical answer!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that line $(1)$ represents the equation of the tangent line to the curve $y = f(x)$ at the point $(p,f(p))$. Since $(3,0)$ is not on the curve $y = f(x)$, you applied this formula incorrectly.

Since André gave you the intended way of solving it, I'll show you the geometric way of doing it: similar triangles! Let $O$ be the centre of the circle, let $A$ be the point of tangency on the circle, and let $B$ be the external point $(3,0)$. Draw a vertical line through the circle at point $A$, and let $C$ be the point where this vertical line crosses the $x$-axis. Observe that $\Delta OAB$ is similar to $\Delta OCA$. Hence, by computing the scale factor in two different ways, it follows that:
$$
\frac{OC}{OA} = \frac{OA}{OB} \iff x = \frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: I did the geometric resolution as you indicated, very interesting. Thank you!